# asp.net checkbox in gridview Why my checkbox is not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web, checkbox

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdInvPending" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
     CssClass="table table-hover" AllowSorting="true">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LeagueName" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral"
         HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" ItemStyle-Width="250px" SortExpression="name" />                                                   
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAccepter" Visible="true" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRefuser" Visible="true" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Difficult to tell without knowing what's going on in your code-behind.  Is your grid view actually data-binding? (you could debug the grdInvPending.DataBound event and confirm that it's actually being hit).  Is your data source actually returning any records?  You say that your "checkbox is not showing up" - does that mean you are seeing a table being rendered on the web page, but just no checkboxes in it?

Comment: You are using TemplateField. Controls inside TemplateField will not pick up the value from the DataSource. You need to assign value to them.

Comment: yes i have databind the grid and it is hitting it and what do you meen assign value to them?

Comment: Your checkbox control is missing Text property. Add "Text" property to your checkbox control. Appears to be some quirk in GridView control.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Actually the TemplateField controls will pickup the values from datasource, if you assign one. Here is an example: `Text="<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>"` assuming your datasource has a "CustomerName" field and your control has a Text property.

Comment: @XamiYen.. I mean the same.... Controls inside TemplateField can not use `DataField`. Values should be assigned to them explicitly by using `Eval`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the whole mess in the columns tag, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAccepter" Visible="true" runat="server" />
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightCoral" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRefuser" Visible="true" runat="server" />
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

While I really like grid view? I think the "instant" you start customizing it - and adding custom controls? I then jump over and almost ALWAYS now use the listview.

Now the listview "seems" to have a truckload more markup, but I often generate my columns by using the wizard (setup a data source). I then blow out (delete) the edit temple, alternating, temple, and a few more.

The end result? Well, you get nice grid but NOW you can freely drag + drop controls from the toolbox right into the markup.

Each new control you add?
It does NOT need the TemplateField->ItemTempalte (that's two extra open + close markup tags. So the listview "seems" a bit more to chew on, but in the long run, I find it MUCH nicer.

So, here is a listview as a grid:

```
    <link href="Content/cuscosky.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr id="myTable1" style="">
    
     <td><asp:Label ID="IDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /></td>
     <td><asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
     <td><asp:TextBox ID="tQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qty") %>' style="width:40px" /></td>
     <td><asp:TextBox ID="tUnitPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UnitPrice") %>' style="width:70px;text-align:right" /></td>
     <td><asp:TextBox ID="tCost" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qty") * Eval("UnitPrice") %>' style="width:70px;text-align:right"  /></td>
            
    </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <LayoutTemplate>
   <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" >
     <tr runat="server" style="">
     <th runat="server">ID</th>
     <th runat="server">Description</th>
     <th runat="server">Qty</th>
     <th runat="server">UnitPrice</th>
     <th runat="server">Cost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
  </table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

So, you get to use normal asp.net controls, and "only" a cost of <//td>.
so while the control "seems" a bit more messy, "when" you going to have lots of controls as opposed to just autogenerated columns, then I jump over to the listview.

I also googled for a decent style sheet, so the above markup produces this grid:

[image]

Not a big deal - but as a FYI? The more custom controls you start dropping into gridView? Well, if you plans are for lots of controls - then I quite much suggest listview since you don't need that itemtemplate stuff over and over.

Comment: Your original post did not have that markup as such. Your new posted markup you have now? Yes, it should work. We assume that the grid displays something - but the check boxes do not? So, data such as LeagueName displays fine and shows when you run this? correct? Is there code in itemdatabound event we don't know about? If the LeagueName is displaying fine then the check boxes should also display. We thus missing additonal details here - it not clear what. Now of course if LeagueName does not display then of course the checkboxs will not either - so you verify that LeagueName displays fine?

Answer (score 0):

Add `"Text"` property to your checkbox. If you don't want any text to show next to your checkbox, then use `Text="&nbsp;"`. That should do the trick. Here is your full markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectAll" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectOne" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Microsoft document on how to add checkboxes in GridView has good information that you might find useful. Here is the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs